# multiple parameter mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

find the project that's the least expensive AND has the highest number of ratings AND has the highest average rating. is this the correct method to do it?

```
exports.getBestEconomicalProject = function(number, callback){  
    var result = ProjectModel.find().sort({averageCost: 1}, {ratingCount : -1}, {averageRating : -1}).select({_id: 1}).limit(number).exec(
            function(err, projects) {
                callback(null, projects)
            }
        );  
    return result;
}
```

Comment: are you storing averageCost and ratingCount and averageRating in your document?

Comment: yes they are attributes in each docuyment

Comment: sounds like an impossible problem - the least expensive project may have lowest number of ratings and have nowhere near the highest average rating - how do you reconcile that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine all [`sort`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) terms into a single object:

```js
exports.getBestEconomicalProject = function(number, callback){  
    var result = ProjectModel.find()
        .sort({averageCost: 1, ratingCount : -1, averageRating : -1})
        .select({_id: 1})
        .limit(number)
        .exec(
            function(err, projects) {
                callback(null, projects)
            }
        );  
    return result;
}
```

Or use the string format for the `sort`:

```js
exports.getBestEconomicalProject = function(number, callback){  
    var result = ProjectModel.find()
        .sort('averageCost -ratingCount -averageRating')
        .select({_id: 1})
        .limit(number)
        .exec(
            function(err, projects) {
                callback(null, projects)
            }
        );  
    return result;
}
```

Comment: is there a difference in performance between the 2, in terms of runtime for instance?

Comment: string version of sort worked for me - object version or array version didn't